# OpenCover running on a 64bits TeamCity agent

Tags: teamcity, opencover

We're migrating our TeamCity agents from 32bits systems to 64bits and some builds started to fail due to an error in OpenCover.

This is the stacktrace:

> E:/BuildAgent/work/7777662cc87ae003/tools/opencover/opencover.console.exe
>   -returntargetcode -target:E:/BuildAgent/work/7777662cc87ae003/tools/nunit/nunit-console.exe
>   -targetargs:"./myTests.dll /framework=v4.0.30319 /noshadow /nologo /work=output /result:my-tests-results.xml" -filter:"+[*something*]*
>   -[*something.*Test*]*" -output:results.xml -register:user
>
> [10:43:16][Execute test:coverage] An exception occured: Failed to
>   register(user:True,register:True,is64:False):2 the profiler assembly;
>   you may want to look into permissions or using the -register:user
>   option instead. C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe /s  /n /i:user
>   "E:\BuildAgent\work\7777662cc87ae003\tools\opencover\x86\OpenCover.Profiler.dll"
>
> [10:43:16][Execute test:coverage] stack:    at
>   OpenCover.Framework.ProfilerRegistration.ExecuteRegsvr32(Boolean
>   userRegistration, Boolean register, Boolean is64)
>
> [10:43:16][Execute test:coverage]    at
>   OpenCover.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)

Interesting to notice:
1) we're using the '- register:user' as indicated by the error message
2) although our new agent is a 64bits system, the exception indicates that the register method was called w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by registering the 64 bits opencover profiler:

```
regsvr32 /s \{ToolsFolder}\OpenCover\x64\OpenCover.Profiler.dll
```

Comment: Yes I believe that is also mentioned in Usage guide "Build system integration"

Comment: for me, I need to make my gitignore to allow my gitlab project has this file. thanks for the hints